# PhantomJS - Trying to find out if an element is empty or not

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I'm trying to write a simple PhantomJS script where I find an element by ID and determine if it is empty of not.  I've tried a few suggested things such as .childNodes.length, .textContent, etc.
These either result in a null error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('idname').childNodes')
```

Or phantom just crashes and refuses to check the links at all, usually this happens if I run my script twice in a row without much pause. And it will sometimes sit and do nothing.
I've written other scrapers that effectively used getElementById in this way, and they were successful, although there I was just checking if the element existed by checking if it was !== null. Checking manually, this element does exist in all the pages I'm checking, it's just that it sometimes has content and sometimes doesn't (it's a div). Anyway, here is my code:

```
 var fs = require('fs')
 var urls = fs.read('urls.txt').split('\n');

 var page;
 page = require('webpage').create();
 console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
 page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';


 function check_link(url){
     page = require('webpage').create();
     page.open(url, function(status){
         if (status !== 'success') {
             console.log('Unable to access network');
         } else {   
             var error = page.evaluate(function() {
                 return document.getElementById('error-message');
             });
             console.log(error.childNodes.length);
             fs.write('results.csv', error.childNodes.length + ', ' + url + '\n', 'a');
             page.release();
             setTimeout(next_link, 1000);
         }
     });
 }   

 function next_link(){
     var url = urls.shift();

     console.log(url);
     if(!urls){
         phantom.exit(0);
     } else{
         check_link(url);
     }
 }

 next_link();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS provides access to the sandboxed page context (DOM context) through [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) with the following note:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

So you cannot pass the DOM node out of the page context, but you can do everything you want with it *in* the page context and then pass out the result.

```
var errors = page.evaluate(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById('error-message');
    return (e && e.childNodes) ? e.childNodes.length : -1
});
console.log(errors);
```